# Executing a function after animate settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Found this on stack overflow the other day http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LERrGG.

I think this is a great pen that could be really useful. The only problem is that there is no ability to call a function after the timer runs out. I was trying to implement this with no success.

How do I edit the code so that it becomes a useful timer i.e. it 'runs out'?

```
(function animate() {
  theta += 0.5;
  theta %= 360;
  var x = Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
  var y = Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
  var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
  timer.setAttribute('d', d);
  setTimeout(animate, t)
})();
```

Comment: It **is** a "normal" `setTimeout()`. The way this code is written, the timer never "runs out". Can you clarify your question?

Comment: How then do I make it run out so that the timer can be used?

Comment: What does that mean? You have to explain exactly what it is you want to do or else nobody will be able to help.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do something when the circle is complete?

Comment: I'm really bad with javascript and especially animations. (my background is in server analytics) I was just messing around and thought it would be cool to have a useful timer. Unfortunately I don't quite understand how the sittimeout() is used in this instance.

Comment: Yes when the circle is complete time should have run out.

Comment: The setTimeout calls the same function, incrementing the circle a little each time, with a small delay, and that's how animations are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine that a complete circle has been painted by checking to see if `theta` ends up smaller than when it started out:

```
(function animate() {
  var oldTheta = theta;
  theta += 0.5;
  theta %= 360;
  if (theta < oldTheta) {
    // the timer has "run out"
  }
  else {
    var x = Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
    var y = Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
    var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
    timer.setAttribute('d', d);
    setTimeout(animate, t);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if theta smaller than 360.

```
  (function animate() {
  theta += 0.5;
  var x = Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
  var y = Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
  var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
  timer.setAttribute('d', d);
 if(theta<360) setTimeout(animate, t);
 else doSomething();
})();
```

Comment: if the value of thea is higher than 360 it shouldn't call the setTimeout function

Comment: Oh oh I see what you mean. Sorry. :)